# Delay functions in Anylogic System Dynamics

Tags: java, anylogic, systemdynamics, vensim

What function in AnyLogic-System Dynamics is equivalent to the Delay3 function in Vensim? The Delay3 function in Vensim is used for material delay (e.g. when goods are delayed by 3 days). The syntax in Vensim is: Delay3(input, delayTime).

I tried using functions smooth and Delay but I'm not sure if that is correct.

Comment: why would this question be closed if it's cleearly asking about what java code to use?

Comment: also the question is extremely clear and focused... If i wanted to edit the question, i wouldn't even know how to make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

Delay3 doesn't correspond to a 3 days delay, instead it corresponds to a third order exponential delay.

Remember you can construct yourself using stock and flows a delay of any order you want, it's a good exercise to understand the differences.

The equivalent function in AnyLogic is delay3
You can find it in the help documentation: [delay3](https://anylogic.help/advanced/functions/delay3.html#delay3)